# Grails select tag name id override, how to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, grails

I have a grails select tag, whose name that renders as an idea is a bean that's a child of a bean so the name has the format of "supplier.code", I need it in the format of "supplierCode" but if I change the name in order to affect the id it won't recognise and save the value in the bean (when validating the page reloads without the chosen value). I need it this way so that I can use it with a Jquery validation plugin, which won't accept "supplier.code" as valid code.

Is there a way to override how the id is given without disrupting the bean save? would it be possible by contstructing a custom tag?

```
<g:select name="supplier.code" from="${data.Vendor.list().sort{ it.description }}" optionKey="code" optionValue="description" value="${invoiceInstance?.supplier?.code}" default="none" noSelection="['':'-Choose-']" />
```

EDIT-----

I'm not sure a custom tag will work (on its own) becasue as long as I change the id it won't save the bean. Perhaps, I just need to change the name in the template to "supplierCode" and then at the controller level grab the value stored in "supplierCode" and then dynamically add this to the bean as supplier.code? I will try that out...

Answer (score 0):

doh! it was so simple,

```
invoiceInstance.supplier = Vendor.findByCode(params['supplierCode'])
```

And then changed the name to "supplierCode"